# Is this the right way to use std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to save a copy of `char[10]` in the below code snippet, just would like to know if this is the right way to use `std::move` and this will in fact save a copy of `char[10]` as `Struct2` object is being constructed.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


struct Struct1 {
    int a;
    string b;
    char c[10];
};

struct Struct2 {
    const Struct1 struct1;
    int d;
    string e;
};

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    auto b = "b";
    char c[10] = "12345";
    Struct1 struct1{a, b};
    strcpy(struct1.c, c);
    Struct2 str2{std::move(struct1), 10, "e"}; //<-- no copy of struct1.c, right?
    cout << str2.struct1.c << endl;
}
```

Also is there a better syntax in construct Struct2, if I dont want to copy `char[10]` twice(`Struct1` will not be used other than as a field of `Struct2`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C array has the same semantics for move and copy. In other words a copy and a move of a C array do the exact same thing.

The advantage will be on `std::string`, e.g. member `Struct1::b`.

And yes, that is the correct syntax/usage of `std:: move`.

Comment: does this mean it always `steal` by `move` or `copy` to a new address?

Comment: No! It means it does not steal. It will copy the contents.

Comment: so if I want to avoid copy, I should really wrap struct1 in a shared_ptr?

Comment: I have added an example for you as another answer

Comment: @tesla1060 `move` is  a device of transferring ownership. it have anything meaningful different from copy only for class-types. objects of primitive types do not have ownership, arrays don't have ownership (while an element of array may have).

Comment: There is a piece in CppCon 2020 about move semantics : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW-zGD6RDCM

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the variables with the debugger you can see that the only entity moved is the non-POD ("plain old data") string `b`.  Before the move you have:
[image]

and after the move you have:
[image]

You will see that the 'b' string ***data*** has been copied to a new memory location and the old one is erased but it still has its original buffer at 0x00edfe40

As others have said, `std::move` is more concerned about transfer of ownership, ensuring that copies are not kept, moreso than avoiding copying memory around per-se.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polluting my previous answer, here is a suggestion:

If you want to use unique_ptr, try something like this.  Unfortunately `make_unique` doesn't play nicely with initialiser lists so you have to define a non-default constructor (*unless anyone out there knows a way around this?*).

```
class Struct1
{
public:
    int a;
    string b;
    char c[10];

    Struct1::Struct1(int _a, string const&& _b, char const* _c) : a(_a), b(_b)
    {
        strcpy_s(c, 10, _c);
    }
};

using Struct1_unique = std::unique_ptr<Struct1>;

typedef struct 
{
    Struct1_unique pStruc1;
//  const Struct1 struct1;
    int d;
    string e;
}
tsStruct2;


int main() {
    int a = 10;
    auto b = "b";
    char c[10] = "12345";
    //Struct1 struct1{ a, b };
    Struct1_unique pStruc1 = std::make_unique<Struct1>(a, b, c);
    //strcpy_s(pStruc1->c, 10, c);
    tsStruct2 str2{ std::move(pStruc1), 10, "e" };
    cout << str2.pStruc1->c << endl;
    str2.pStruc1.reset();
}
```

So, once again, before the move you have:
[image]

and after:

[image]

You can see that the ownership of the object has been transferred (pStruc1 now "empty") without doing any copying; the pointers to the object and the string data within have not changed.  The `reset` at the end deallocates the object.